# Data binding not working when calling a function inside controller from script tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am calling a function inside controller from inside script tag in HTML page as follows

```
    <script>
function initMap() {
  var scope = $('#loginDetailPage').scope();
  scope.showLocationDetail();
  console.log('scope', scope);
}
</script>
<div id="loginDetailPage" class="canvas">
  <div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <div class="row content">
      <div class="grid profile">

        <div class="col-md-8" style="text-align:right;" >
          <p><a href="" title="Change background"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"> Add photos to gallery</i></a></p>
          <div class="grid-header-business">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align:left; color:black;">
          <h3>{{vm.locationDetailObj.name}}</h3>{{vm.data.test}}
          <hr>
          <label> Address</label>
          <p>{{vm.locationDetailObj.formatted_address}}</p>
          <p>Phone: {{vm.locationDetailObj.formatted_phone_number}}</p>
          <small rating-stars rating="vm.locationDetailObj.rating"></small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-body">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active"  id="timeline">
        <p class="lead">Location</p>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="map" style="width:70%;height:400px;"></div>
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY=places&callback=initMap"></script>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is my function in controller

```
    (function() {
  angular.module('myApp').controller('locationDetailCtrl', ['$scope', 'location', '$routeParams', function ($scope, location, $routeParams){
    var vm = this;

    $scope.showLocationDetail = function() {
      vm.locationObj = location.getLocationDetail();
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: vm.locationObj.geometry.location.lat, lng: vm.locationObj.geometry.location.lng},
        zoom: 15
      });

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

      service.getDetails({
        placeId: vm.locationObj.place_id
      }, function(place, status) {
        vm.locationDetailObj = place;
        console.log('place: ', vm.locationDetailObj);
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: place.geometry.location
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
            'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
            place.formatted_address + '</div>');
            infowindow.open(map, this);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }]);
})();
```

Here Data Binding does not work for variables inside  $scope.showLocationDetail function. But if I write anything on $scope object outside showLocationDetail function, data binding works as expected.

PS: I am calling $scope.showLocationDetail from script tag present in HTML page.

Comment: Where's the `ng-controller` directive for your html?

Comment: @JustinJmnz I have not written whole code. I am using ng-route. It gets the template and initialize the controller. I write anything outside test function in controller it is working as expected

Comment: What is `data`? You can't add properties to something that wasn't defined.

Comment: @JustinJmnz As I said I have not written the whole code. In my controller I have define data. $scope.data = {}

Comment: @JustinJmnz I thought I might be having problem because of nested scopes so I used object data so that it can use prototypal Inheritance. Also I am not getting any error.

Comment: Again, are you providing the `ng-controller="locationDetailCtrl as vm"` in your html? I don't see it.

Comment: @JustinJmnz I have taken care of those stuffs while routing. Here is the snippet. .when('/locationDetail/:locationId', {
              templateUrl : 'location/locationDetail.view.html',
              controller: 'locationDetailCtrl',
              controllerAs: 'vm'
            }) . And as I told you am not getting any error. My function inside controller is being called. If I miss things you are pointing out I would definitely get error

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt to what I think you're trying to do..

```
// index.html
<html ng-app="app">
    <!-- Some html stuff -->
    <div id="loginDetailPage" ng-controller="LoginController">
        some stuff
        {{ test() }}
        {{ data.greet }}
    </div>
</html>
```

In your controller file

```
// LoginController.js
angular.controller("LoginController",
    function LoginController($scope) {
        $scope.data = {};
        $scope.test = function() {                            
            $scope.data.greet = "Hello";
        }
    }
);
```

This should work, you need to call the function `test`. Nothing shows up for `data.greet` because it was never attached to the `$scope`. `$scope.test()` was never called in your example.

Also, I wouldn't use jQuery combined with Angular.

Comment: I put debugger inside $scope.test(). It is being called. I checked those things already

Comment: Also I need to make call to controller from function defined inside script tag

Comment: Can you edit your question to supply more information then. I have no idea what `$("#loginDetailPage").scope();` is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

My variables were not adding on angular watches. It was because I was calling function inside my controller from scope object which I got using jQuery. So I used following code to add variable to angular watch list

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    vm.test = "Success";
    vm.locationDetailObj = place;
 });
```

It is working as expected.